# Join query where table references itself

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm using Oracle 10, but the best way to ask this question is with an example.

```
select * 
  from t1, t2
 where t1.id = t2.id
   and t1.otherID = (select max(otherID) 
                       from t2 
                      where id = THE ID FROM THE OUTER QUERY T1
                    )
```

I think you see where I'm trying to go with this.  I need to reference `t1` in the subquery to join it to the max of `t2`.

I need to know how to create a query like this.

"THE ID FROM THE OUTER QUERY T1" is where my confusion is.

I tried using `t1.id`, but did not get results.

Comment: If this question is no longer valid, you should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
join (select id, max(otherID) as max_otherID
      from t2 
      group by id
 ) a ON a.id = t1.id and a.max_otherID = t1.otherID
```

Using a sub-query on the join often gives better performance than using it in the where clause.